# How to change font on CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc, fonts

I am on CyanogenMod 10.1, and I installed a font from FlipFont. But, I could not find the option to change it on the display settings.

If anyone has any idea about this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Font Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.font.installer). This app requires ROOT.

Comment: It worked. But while selecting _Install_ , it says like Font Installer has stopped working unfortunately. Any idea ?

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @Mirko Have you tried Font Installer?

Comment: Yes and it crashes beautifully. iFont does the job though